# Sending Array Using Ajax to Django App

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, django

So I have some jquery and ajax that collects data from checkbox values. This part is working, I used `alert` to debug the array to see if the appropriate values are being collected when the checkboxes are ticked.

```
                var myCheckboxes = new Array();
                $("input:checked").each(function() {
                    myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'createEvent/',
                    data:{
                        name: name,
                        myCheckboxes: myCheckboxes,
                    }
                });
```

However on my receiving end I have:

```
def createEvent(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        member = request.POST.getlist('myCheckboxes')
        print(member)
```

Member is an empty array. What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Try printing out `request.POST.get('myCheckboxes')`. It's most likely you're just receiving a string from AJAX.

Comment: get an empty array :(

Comment: Did you try adding (dateType: 'json')?

Comment: You need  `request.POST.getlist('myCheckboxes[]')`